# Subquery with the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to find the most optima way to select rows from table with the same name like particular record.

```
ID  NAME
10  A
10  C
10  B
20  A
30  D
31  B
```

And after select:

```
ID  NAME
20  A
31  B
```

I thought about something like this:

```
select * from table
where name in (select name from table where id = 10).
```

Is there any other options ?

Comment: Please explain the logic.  It is not obvious.  What particular record?

Comment: When you run your query, what results do you get, and how do they differ from the results you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
select name
from table
group by name
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id <> 10 and
      t.name in (select t2.name from t t2 where t2.id = 10);
```

Oh, that is basically your query.  You can also do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when id = 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name) as has_name_10
      from t
     ) t
where has_name_10 = 1 and id <> 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
with diff_name as (
select * from(
select 10 id , 'A' name from dual
union
select 10 id , 'B' name from dual
union
select 10 id , 'C' name from dual
union
select 20 id , 'A' name from dual
union
select 30 id , 'D' name from dual
union
select 31 id , 'B' name from dual))
select distinct b.* from diff_name a,
                diff_name b
where a.name=b.name
and a.id <>b.id
and a.id = 10
```